# Should small entities such as Country/Regions and University Studies be considered microservices?

Tags: microservices

I am designing a job search app where I have entities like:

- Candidate User
- Company User
- Offers
- Province Entity related in One To Many relationship with Country
- University Entity related in One To Many relationship with Degree
  Entity. The Degree stores additional information about the Degree.

The Candidate User, the Company User and the Offers are linked to a Country and a Province.
Each Candidate Profile is linked to an n Degrees.

Should I build these 5 entities in a single module or split it into 4 or 5?

On the one hand, I think that the Countries/Provinces could go into a microservice since they can be reused in other applications and that perhaps in the future they will be related to other new entities.
I think the same with the University Degrees, that in the future I might want to relate them to new entities not related to the Offers.

On the other hand, I think that dividing the application so much is counterproductive, and that in the case of wanting to extend the entities in the future, it could be done within the same module.

What I do think is clear is that the Company User and the Candidate User were part of the same module, in which I also doubt whether to include the Offers since, at the moment, they are a single class.

What should I do?

Comment: I'm a bit at loss on where the *service* part of a "Province Microservice" might hide.

Comment: @tofro From my point of view, Country/Province it is included since it can offer data such as the telephone prefix and that it is associated with many entities, so it is a Class that can be reusable. But like I said, I'm pretty lost and all opinions are welcome.

Comment: Note microservices provide a *service*, not *data* (it's just that some data of the input parameters might be relevant to the service provided). If you're not saying what service this might be, the question is pretty moot. Let's assume you provide a simple MS that *counts* things and returns the count, or an MS that *stores* things, for example, it is relatively irrelevant what data the input objects provide.

Comment: When you use the words "perhaps in the future", remember YAGNI (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/Yagni.html).

Comment: I do not know why this question has several negatives. The fact that there are real world examples implementing this anti-pattern shows that there is value in explaining the consequences of designing this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, dividing like this seems an overkill. This does not mean that it cannot be done but that it will bring too much work.

First, it looks a case of the [Entity Services Antipattern](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/12/entity-services-antipattern/) leading to anemic services. Performance will be really affected by parsing a lot of messages and network communication. Even if one microservice is the source of truth you will still need to copy (or cache) a local data to each microservice anyway. If you feel that you are spending too much code with Rest services and clients instead of doing logic this may be the case. Also, how would any microservice handle in one of them fail?

There are some forces that leads you to a more distributed or concentrated architecture.

To separate into more microservices:

- Different escalation needs
- Different security requirements
- Different teams developing
- Being able to fail without affecting other services
- ...

To Join

- Need to execute transactions.
- Code cohesion ( like Country and Province )
- Time dependency
- ...

I do not see any force that is leading you use separate microservices. A good architect takes decisions based on needs. There are some alternatives:

- Use a [modular monolith](https://www.techtarget.com/searchapparchitecture/tip/Understanding-the-modular-monolith-and-its-ideal-use-cases) that can be separated into microservices latter
- If you are really trying to code the new LinkedIn you can separate by usage focusing on subdomains. Like:

  - Microservice that handles the candidate web page
  - Microservice that handles the companies web page
  - Common microservice for offers
- In some cases a common lib with hardcoded data can work (Countries and provinces do not change too much).
- A service oriented architecture with a common database will allow you to keep those one to many relationship with foreign keys.

There is not a single good architecture. Just trade offs even if some of them will become evidently too expensive soon.